ansible-pullを使ってリモートリポジトリ上のplaybookを呼び出したい
■ developブランチのsandbox.ymlファイル
---
- name: Loop through commands and display progress
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "helloworld"

■ コマンド
ansible-pull -U git@github.com:[user name]/[remote repo name].git --checkout develop sandbox.yml

■ コマンドの返り値
Starting Ansible Pull at [date]
/usr/bin/ansible-pull -U git@github.com:[user name]/[remote repo name].git --checkout develop sandbox.yml
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring:
localhost.localdomain
localhost | CHANGED => {
    "after": "[hash 1]",
    "before": "[hash 2]",
    "changed": true,
    "remote_url_changed": false
}
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring:
localhost.localdomain
ERROR! Specified inventory, host pattern and/or --limit leaves us with no hosts to target.

このように出てしまいhello worldに成功しませんでした
※ ローカル環境にてansible-playbook sandbox.ymlを実行した際は実行に成功しました
成功させるにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか
